# struggling to set up WP tests

Tags: unit-tests

I want to contribute to a guys plugin (TimberWp).  I'd like to do it with tests.  his plugin has a test dir that looks just like the wp-cli scaffolded dir.  all v standard.

Iv'e managed to get as far as installing wp-cli,  phpunit (already had that) and I got past the couldn't connect to mysql issue (make it use the mamp php5.4 version)

now, running:

```
WP_TESTS_DIR=~/sites/kindling/wp-unit-tests phpunit
```

gives me

Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/willbarker/sites/kindling/wp-unit-tests/includes/bootstrap.php on line 7

So i made sure my path to phpunit is set in my php.ini

```
  timber git:(master) ✗ php -r 'foreach (explode(":", get_include_path()) as $path) echo $path . PHP_EOL;'
.
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

So i am out of ideas how to get phpunit working with WP.  Have i got the right version of phpunit? its a phar, is that why i can't include files from it? I'm obviously confused / running into the extent of my knowledge. Here is my installed phpunit version:

```
➜  timber git:(master) ✗ phpunit --which 
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

Comment: Between PHPUnit and _plugin's_ tests I am fuzzy how this relates to WP. Does plugin provide instructions on testing it? Have you tried inquiring with its developers?

Comment: rarst - WP has a test set up that plugins use in a fairly standardised way.  I've downloaded the plugins tests & im trying to get them to run by installing the WP test suite.  If somebody comes accross this that uses WP tests i expect it will turn out to be a simple thing ive missed in the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.  Possibly more by luck than judgement

As phpunit is a system thing, not a project thing phptherightway said to use pear to insall.  I had it installed using composer.

So i installed it with pear:

http://ramonroche.com/2011/11/installing-phpunit-on-os-x-using-mamp-via-pear/

and then update my mamp php.ini include path

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpunit"
```

Then i cd'd to the plugin dir and ran

```
WP_TESTS_DIR=~/sites/kindling/wp-unit-tests phpunit
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup similar to yours, with MAMP. I also have had this problem with PHPUnit. It seems that no matter what you do, PHPUnit does not recognize the `include_path` from MAMP. You have to add the correct path to the `php.ini` in `/private/etc/`.